# Метод, срабатывающий каждый час

Tags: c#

Только учусь программировать, хочу написать небольшое консольное приложение, для которой требуется метод, срабатывающий через определенный интервал времени. Например, каждый час. Встречал решения для WinForms и WPF, но не могу найти реализацию для консольных приложений.

Comment: А в чем проблема написать тоже на консоли? Разница только в выводе информации должна быть (вместо `textBox1.Text = ...;` будет `Console.WriteLine(...);`). Очень советую для начала попытаться все это реализовать вам (без нашей помощи), а уж потом задавать вопрос сюда со всеми вашими попытками. Тогда и вопрос будет не столь общий, а конкретно по делу...

Comment: "timer programmatically c#"

Answer (score 0):

```
var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);

var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
{
    MyMethod();   
}, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019433/calling-a-method-every-x-minutes